How to inject configurations in forRoot in Angular module
We have a rather complex angular application, and need to load configurations on load. We accomplish this by using a InjectionToken which we populate in main.ts:
fetch('./config/config.json')
    .then((resp) => resp.json())
    .then((config) => {
        if (config.production) {
            enableProdMode();
            if (window && config.removeConsole) {
                window.console.log = function () {};
            }
        }
        platformBrowserDynamic([{ provide: APP_CONFIG, useValue: config }])
            .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
            .catch((err) => console.error(err));
    });

In AppModule are we able to read some of the configurations. For our authentification service this is done by adding the InjectionToken as a dependency:
providers: [
        {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: initializeKeycloak,
            multi: true,
            deps: [KeycloakService, APP_CONFIG],
        },
]

But we are also dependent on injecting an AppId for a vendor module (Intercom), which I'm not able to wrap my head around.
Can someone guide me to how I inject the config to a modules forRoot?
imports: [
        IntercomModule.forRoot({
            appId: config.intercom.appId, /// Need a reference for config here?
            updateOnRouterChange: true,
        }),
    ],

Is it possible to use a provider somehow to solve this? The problem is the module is from a vendor, and not something we can change unfortunate.

Define a const that will be empty, which will be populated by the APP_INITIALIZER, you can also define default properties which the config can use here!
export let configPlaceholder: any = {};

Then you can either set the config above the platformBrowserDynamic section, or inside a custom useFactory to this const variable
method 1
fetch('./config/config.json')
    .then((resp) => resp.json())
    .then((config) => {
        if (config.production) {
            enableProdMode();
            if (window && config.removeConsole) {
                window.console.log = function () {};
            }
        }
        configPlaceholder = config;
        platformBrowserDynamic([{ provide: APP_CONFIG, useValue: config }])
            .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
            .catch((err) => console.error(err));
    });

Method 2
providers: [
        {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: (config: AppConfig) => { 
                 return () => { 
                     configPlaceholder = config.intercom.appId; 
                     return new Promise(resolve => {
                         resolve();
                     });
                 }
            },
            multi: true,
            deps: [APP_CONFIG],
        },
]

Then finally, connect this variable to forRoot
imports: [
    IntercomModule.forRoot({
        appId: configPlaceholder?.intercom?.appId, /// Need a reference for config here?
        updateOnRouterChange: true,
    }),
],


Thanks for replying. It defiantly throw me in the correct direction! There is just a type above. The useFactory need to return a Function:
useFactory: (config: AppConfig) => {
return () => {
configPlaceholder = config.intercom.appId;
};
}
